# Android switch not turning off

Tags: android

From API 14 android introduce the Switch
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html
If I try to use

```
_switchOnOff.setChecked(false);
```

the Switch change it's color correctly from Blu to Grey, but do not return to off position.

I tried also

```
_switchOnOff.toggle();
```

But it's the same, the color is corrected, but the position of the switch remain the same.
So i do not understand, it is normal ?
Is there a method for switch movement ?
Thanks in advance

I created a sample project with only the Switch and it have no problem, instead in my project the switch do not work

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is for programming questions, and this is not a programming question. If you wish to report what you think is a bug in the Android SDK, prepare a sample project that demonstrates the bug, then visit http://b.android.com and post your issue with the sample project.

Comment: thanks for the welcome, but mine is a question, i want to know wich is the way for doing wath i asked. I't mine first question, sorry for my error. How i can edit the question ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. `toggle()` works just fine on Android 4.1 or 4.2, changing both the color, thumb position, and displayed text. You are welcome to create a sample project that demonstrates your issue and link to it from your question. You can edit your question by clicking the "edit" link below the question itself.

Comment: i created i test apk and confirm that it work, so the problem is on my application. it is veri strange that the color change but not the position. I will investigate and report here news.
Thanks for now :-)

Comment: @Testato can you provide that API so we can test your claim?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

My MainUI was unresponsive because the main thread worked on a long task.
By eliminating this long task the _switchOnOff.setChecked(false) command return to work.